# Bing Maps Runtime Error Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, bing-maps, windows-8.1

When I run the app of Windows 8.1 with Bing Map integration, I get following error.

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in DistanceApp.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'Map'
>   was not found in namespace 'Bing.Maps'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]
>
> Additional information: The text associated with this error code could
>   not be found.
>
> Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'Map' was not found in
>   namespace 'Bing.Maps'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,10" >
            <Maps:Map Name="bingMap" HomeRegion="US" Credentials="{Bing Key}" />
        </Grid>
```

I can see map design time and it builds successfully. But when I run this error comes to InitializeComponent() method.

I'm using VS 2013 RTM and Windows 8.1.

I searched a lot but I didn't get anything.

Please help me

Comment: Is there anything in **InitializeComponent()**?

Comment: no. I didn't change anything in InitializeComponent(). Even I created new project with just Bing Map Control...still same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's solved. I changed the project platform target from x86 to x64 and its solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error `Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as '<name of key>' was not found in namespace '<my namespace>'` with UWP for two of my resources in my application resource dictionary.

For the first resource I had accidentally used `x:Name` instead of `x:Key`.

For the second I had set both the `x:Key` and `x:Name` attributes, and removing the `x:Name` attribute fixed it.